# Cannot execute SonarScanner for .NET project on Jenkins because "dotnet-sonarscanner: not found"

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, sonarqube

Quite new with Sonar. So far I was able to configure in jenkins my sonarqube server and run maven apps with following code.

```
withSonarQubeEnv('sonarserver') {

     sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar'
             
    }
```

This runs successfully and do the analysis plus the maven build and generates a war file. Also I´m able to see analysis in sonarqube page

Now I´m trying to do the same for .net core app. I installed sonarscanner following this [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6954799)

First step was successfully run, I got:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed.
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-sonarscanner
```

So I created following code next:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('sonarserver') {
       sh '''
          
          dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"proyject-key" //key was generated in sonarqube x new proj.
          dotnet build solution.sln
          dotnet-sonarscanner end
        
        '''
```

But now I´m getting:

```
+ dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:project-key
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar-test-dotnet@tmp/durable-00ff368b/script.sh: 3: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar-test-dotnet@tmp/durable-00ff368b/script.sh: dotnet-sonarscanner: not found
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation which you mentioned, the executed commands should be:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"proyject-key" //key was generated in sonarqube x new proj.
dotnet build solution.sln
dotnet sonarscanner end
```

instead of:

```
dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"proyject-key" //key was generated in sonarqube x new proj.
dotnet build solution.sln
dotnet-sonarscanner end
```

Replace `dotnet-sonarscanner` by the `dotnet sonarscanner`.

Answer (score 0):

This stage work it for me.

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment { 
                PROYECT_FOLDER = 'xxx'
                PROYECT_NAME = 'xxx'
                PROYECT_TEST_FOLDER = 'xxt'
                PROYECT_TEST_NAME = 'Mxxx'
                SONAR_KEY_PROYECT = 'xx'
                SONAR_URL = 'xxx'
                SONAR_LOGIN = 'xx' //Key get from sonar
            }
stages {
```

......

```
 stage('Build + SonarQube analysis') {
          environment { 
                MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME = tool name: 'SonaScanner.NetCore'
            }
         steps {
             withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube') {
                sh "dotnet ${MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll  begin /k:'${SONAR_KEY_PROYECT}' /d:sonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL} /d:sonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN} " 
                sh "dotnet build ${PROYECT_FOLDER}/${PROYECT_NAME} --configuration Release --no-restore"
                sh "dotnet ${MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.login=${SONAR_LOGIN}}"
             }
         }
     }
```